# 18.04 - Changing x-window-manager background

Tags: 18.04, xorg

I am trying to launch a standalone app without the ubuntu-desktop and gdm. I can launch the app with x-window-manager. Is there any way to change the brown background of the x-window-manager ?.

[image: Sample image of x-window-manager]

Steps to launch the app.

1. Keep only the following scripts in /etc/X11/Xsession.d/

40x11-common_xsessionrc

70im-config_launch

2. Add the following line in ~/.xsessionrc

```
x-window manager &
gedit
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this on Ubuntu 18.04 with gdm3 and ubuntu-desktop.. it is showing blue background.. I will try without gdm3 and ubuntu-desktop.. but I would like your way to reproduce the same brown background color.. can you guide how to reproduce?

Comment: I tried without gdm3 and ubuntu-desktop.. It is still showing blue background..

Comment: YuganTej Added the steps in question. Thanks. Can share the pic of blue background

Comment: Hi.. I will share you the pic.. I just tried in your way n got black background..but I hv some tweaking.. So now I will try with fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04..can you confirm is your 0S Ubuntu 18.04?? 0r derivatives like xubuntu kubuntu lubuntu??

Comment: I tried you way with live iso 0f Ubuntu 18.04 and getting black background..

Comment: My setup is Ubuntu 18.04. Is there any way to change the background ?

Comment: to be frank... I am really trying to find out. But I am struck with the point of brown.. Yesterday I got blue color with tweaked Ubuntu 18.04.. today I tried your way and it is black.. any way I am still trying to get some !dea.. will get back if I found anything.. But the color brown is making me crazy..